# Sending emails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

I've set up confirmable with devise and am sending emails in development and test mode. However, I couldn't find any good tutorials for triggering emails for other situations using devise.

For example if a user makes a reservation on my app- how can I email a confirmation to them?

Answer (score 0):

[ActionMailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) would be a good place to start.